# Trying to get property of non-object in codeigniter class my_exception

Tags: codeigniter

I encounter this error in my CI code

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: core/MY_Exceptions.php

Line Number: 11
```

and this is my CI code
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $CI =& get_instance();

    var_dump($CI);
}
```

I don't know why this happen, wherein in the documentation it says the same syntax.

Is there anyone here know about this?
What to do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New to me, but I found this and this might help

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-67859-post-342719.html

> When extending the CI Exception class, there is no way to get the
>   instance with "get_instance()" because as what i've seen, CI isn't
>   loading the core before the Exception controller. I need some basic
>   functions to generate my 404 error pages, so this behavious is
>   completely useless for me as it only handles static output.